# Do you know what video codec is used for messengers?

Tags: video-streaming, msn-messenger, yahoo-messenger

I'd like to know the video codec used for MSN, yahoo, QQ or any other XMPP messengers.

Thanks for help.

Comment: codec? what do you mean? protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *video codecs* it's something like this:

- Skype: [On2's VP7](http://broadcastengineering.com/newsrooms/skype-on2-technologies-truemotion/).
- Yahoo! Messenger: [JPEG 2000](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000143.shtml), i.e. only I-frames.
- Google talk: [H264 and others](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html).
- MSN Messenger: [Siren Codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_Codec).
- iChat: [H.264/AVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IChat).